# Is there a way to have access to Simulacrum as a Warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, simulacrum

Is it possible to get the *simulacrum* spell as a warlock character without multiclassing?

I love playing as a warlock and I love *simulacrum*, so is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, with Magic Items

Any magic items that permits the character to gain access to the *Wish* spell would permit the Warlock a means to cast the spell and have it duplicate the *Simulacrum* spell. This is a common means for high level players to skirt the limitations on *Simulacrum*, which permit only 1 at a time.

The following items meet that criteria:

- Ring of Three Wishes
- Luck Blade
- Efreeti Bottle (roll of 91-100)

Comment: Is your last sentence referring to casting *Simulacrum* and then having each simulacrum wish for another simulacrum? If so, that still requires casting *Simulacrum* without *Wish* first, so I don't know if it's really relevant here.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Not necessarily. Some characters can complete the *wish*-*simulacrum* combination without needing to cast *simulacrum* without *wish*.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Suppose you are a Wizard with Simulacrum and Wish. You could cast both and have 2 simulacrum active since RAW you haven't cast the same spell twice and thus haven't triggered the clause in the last sentence of the spell description.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with **The Genie** subclass (from **Tasha's Cauldron of Everything**). The subclass provides an expanded list of spells for Warlocks to choose from as they level up, including **Wish**, which, as discussed in Pyrotechnical's answer, will let you duplicate the **Simulacrum** spell